# Route53, A record with alias and ip at the same time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a Route53 A record alias to my ELB for `example.com` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html)

and I'm trying to connect domain `example.com` to firebase hosting. 
(to use `example.com` as dynamic link domain)

And firebase setup tool asks me to create two A record `example.com` for two ip addresses.

Route 53 doesn't seem to allow me to have an `alias A` record and `non-alias A` record.

How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported options are to point the domain *only* to Firebase (not any other service, like an ELB), or to use a subdomain or a different domain altogether.

> To use a custom domain for Dynamic Links, the domain must point to Firebase Hosting. If you have a domain you want to use with Dynamic Links and the domain points to a different host, you can either move to Firebase Hosting or create a subdomain hosted by Firebase, which you can use for Dynamic Links.
>
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains

Comment: gracious, you saved me